# Combine two LINQ queries returning bool to one returning bool?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, entity-framework-6.1

I have the following two LINQ queries at the moment (targeting EF 6.1) in a method which returns a `bool?`:

```
if (db.Permissions.Any(p => p.Key == permission && p.Roles.Any(r => !r.IsAllowed 
                                && r.Role.Users.Any(u => u.UserId == userId))))
{
    return false;
}
if (db.Permissions.Any(p => p.Key == permission && p.Roles.Any(r => r.IsAllowed 
                                && r.Role.Users.Any(u => u.UserId == userId))))
{
    return true;
}

return null;
```

The first checks if the user is in any role which is `!IsAllowed` and if so returns `false` (=> user/role is denied the permission, which overrules any "allow"). Then it checks if the user is in any role which has `IsAllowed` set and returns `true` in that case. If the permission is not set for any roles of the user it returns `null`.
This results in two queries to the DB in most cases as `!IsAllowed` is not user very often.

Is there a way to use one query against the DB which directly returns the `bool?`?

Comment: You can always `(bool?)true` and `(bool?)false`;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to order by `IsAllowed`, then select the first one. This should put `false`s first, followed by `true`s. Untested, but I think you get the idea:

```
return db.Permissions.Where(p => p.Key == permission)
    .SelectMany(p => p.Roles.Where(r => r.Role.Users.Any(u => u.UserId == userId))
                            .Select(r => r.IsAllowed))
    .OrderBy(a => a)
    .Select(a => (bool?)a)
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Good idea - will try and report back.

Answer (score 1):

There are probably more elegant solutions out there, but you could join the tables and order by IsAllowed to get the first (if any) record.

```
bool? allowed = (from p in db.Permissions
join r in db.Roles on p.id equals r.Permission_id
join u in db.Users on r.id equals u.Role_id
where p.Key == permission && u.UserId == userId
orderby r.IsAllowed
select r.IsAllowed
).FirstOrDefault();

return allowed;
```

Edit: Oops, someone beat me to it. Same thing, basically.